Using chrome flags in playwright test?
In Playwright, how can I use a chrome://flags/ Chrome browser experimental feature?
For example I want to use "Third-party Cookie Phase Out Facilitated Testing" #tpc-phase-out-facilitated-testing and set it to the "Enabled Force Treatment" option.
I was assuming something along the lines of setting it in playwright.config file, but it's not fully functioning as expected
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Google Chrome',
      use: { 
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'], 
        launchOptions: { 
          args: ['--enable-features=CookieDeprecationFacilitatedTesting:force_eligible/true/disable_3p_cookies/true/disable_ads_apis/false/label/fake_treatment_1%2E1/version/9996'] 
        } 
      },
    },
  ],

